# Interop between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, struct

I have this `struct` in C++:

```
struct TEXTMSGSTR
{
    HWND Sender;
    wchar_t Text[255];
    //wchar_t *Text;
};
```

and in C#:

```
public struct TEXTMSGSTR
{
    public IntPtr Sender;
    public ? Text;
}
```

which I am sending as part of a `COPYDATASTRUCT` message from unmanaged to managed code. What would be the correct construction of the `struct` on the C# side as C# does not have `wchar_t`? I have tried string etc. but of course errors appear!

Can anybody give me some ideas about how to marshal this as well as I am new to this stuff?:

```
TEXTMSGSTR tx = (TEXTMSGSTR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cds.lpData, typeof(TEXTMSGSTR));
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get when you use string?

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188299/marshal-c-struct-array-into-c

All your answers are there. :)

Comment: If you use just straight string without the marshalling part you get a memory corruption.

Comment: Randolpho, i'll check out the link.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct TEXTMSGSTR
{
    public IntPtr Sender;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public string Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad, that worked great.

I really need to read the articles on this, its not easy!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) `LPTStr` or `ByValTStr`.

Also look at my answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793168/calling-unmanaged-function-char-returns-char/806808#806808)

Comment: I'll check out the link, I really need to understand this stuff.  I'm fine with posting the messages its just when I get to the marshalling stuff I get really confused.

Thanks.